# Need yii 1.1.15 extension for dump of my mysql database with funcs and views

Tags: php, function, view, yii, dump

I found and installed extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-dump-db/ for making dump of my mysql database.
It works, but it does not make dumps of funcs and views.
If there is some convinient tool for this, maybe not native yii, but easy to install in yii 1.1.15 app?
Thanks!

Comment: Are your "functions" and "views" stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

> > > Are your "functions" and "views" stored in the database?
> > >       Yes, sure , I just entered several "functions" and "views"  and they are visible in phpmyadmin and HeidiSQL.
> > >       http://s020.radikal.ru/i718/1407/a6/40bed8b1a8a9.png